# in odoo 14 how i can search part of string within a field value

Tags: python, search, odoo

I can search it in oracle using SQL (not plsql) but don't know how to in odoo framework.
Want to find as below -the middle part, which value is variable length-please help how to in python (.py) file where I can have an onchange function to assign this value to a computed field?
[image]

Comment: can you show the fields in odoo? you want to extract data between 2 '-' or you want to find it?

Comment: thanks @SDBot again, as you can see screenshot, the resultset shows what I want to extract partial value ( middle part ) from complete value and assign to computed field.  sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, try this:

```
value_field = fields.Char("Value")
extracted = fields.Char("Extracted", compute="_compute_extracted")

@api.depends('value_field')
def _compute_extracted(self):
    for rec in self:
        split_str = (rec.value_field or '').split('-')
        rec.extracted = split_str[1] if len(split_str) > 1 else ''
```

Comment: much thankful for your help ... again :) it works fine as required. can i extract this value something like in oracle (as in example screenshot) ? it is another type of requirement where i have to start from a particular place as the character '-' is also in start and end. if you can help, as usual, for this. regards

Comment: no problem, happy to help, for the other question, i am not too sure what you mean.

Comment: ok i checked split_str[1]  i can modify the value 1 to x and get value what i want... :) (it means now i started understanding the code with your help)

Comment: yeah, my background is oracle sql & pl/sql, there is a huge difference in concepts and coding on which we can build logics. anyway, will learn with seniors like you :)

Comment: yeah, i am still learning too, i find helping other people with their issue is the easiest way to expand my own logic.